# Reliable Java HTTP request with content length and content type limit

Tags: java, http, timeout, request, limits

I'm searching for realiable (hang-proof) way to get HTTP page in Java with those features:

- stop fetching page if content-type in header will not be text/...
- you can stop fetching page at any time if loaded data exceds limit in bytes (and content-length isn't set in response)
- you can stop fetching page at given time limit

Has apache http client those options ?
I know that after many connections, some small part of all with totally hangs for long time and doesn't respond even to process signals - but this problem can be ommited in running page fetch in other thread, that you can forget after some time limit.
But I still didn't found solution for given problems.

Also my target is to avoid lot of forgotten-zombie-threads downloading huge files so stopping bad download is a priority here.

Comment: java.net.HttpURLConnection does all of this with some trivial additions. Why are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(...)` to make filtering based on content.
2. Override `org.apache.http.message.BasicLineParser#parseRequestLine(...)` with setting limit on maximal cursor right position.
3. You could override [`HttpRequestExecutor.preProcess(...)`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/protocol/HttpRequestExecutor.html#preProcess%28org.apache.http.HttpRequest,%20org.apache.http.protocol.HttpProcessor,%20org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext%29) to set up a timer expiration.

All these requires some effort from your side.

Answer (score 0):

Using httpclient or httpURLConnection:

1. `response.getHeaders` or `connection.getHeaderField`
2. stop read loop after n bytes
3. stop read loop after t (just check `System.currentTimeMillis()`)